# What kind of machine learning model beautiful.ai and others use for slide generation?

Tags: machine-learning-model, generative-models

Hope this question belongs here. Constantly I see advertising from some sites and services that they generate content with AI (machine learning). I was wondering how beautiful.ai, slidebean, even powerpoint use for generating slides and other content. I understand the basics of machine learning but I can’t figure out what kind of model could do this task, from the size and position, color, etc. Not a trivial task at all. Does anyone have an idea about this, model or open-source project you could refer me? Or all of these is just advertising if so what technique is used?

Comment: What kind if content exactly? No way to answer this question as it is...

Comment: My guess is that the slides are not generated with any kind of ML, the user provides some raw content in the form of standardized business data, the system applies some standard statistics to generate some graphs and tables then it's just put together following some template.